# minio local dashboard is not opening

Tags: docker, minio

I have installed minio in docker. It installed successfully and below are logs of the minio server:

[image]

I think all is well but when I invoke localhost:9000 url in browser it redirects to localhost:40793 with error message **site can't be reached**.

[image]

I don't know the issue. Can anyone help ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: how did you install minio in docker? Did you follow the official [doc](https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-docker-quickstart-guide.html)?

Comment: Do you have port 9000 exposed from the docker container?

Can you share the docker command you used?

Comment: @jabbson yes , I did follow the official doc

Comment: @wedm ```docker run -p 9000:9000 --name minio -d -v ~/minio/data:/data -e "MINIO_ROOT_USER={ACCESS_KEY}" -e "MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD={ACCESS_SECRET}" minio/minio server /data```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Addressing the warning about the dynamic port worked for me. I think the issue is that minio serves the API on port 9000, but tries to redirect you to the console when that address visited in the browser (e.g. localhost:9000). The console is on a dynamic port that isn't exposed by docker.

Instead, we can specify the console port using the `--console-address` flag and expose it in the docker command. This worked for me:

```
docker run -p 9000:9000 -p 9001:9001 --name minio -d -v ~/minio/data:/data -e "MINIO_ROOT_USER={ACCESS_KEY}" -e "MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD={ACCESS_SECRET}" minio/minio server --console-address :9001 /data
```

I was then able to visit the console at localhost:9001 (although visiting localhost:9000 also redirected me there).

Comment: For usage with Docker Compose: `command: minio server --console-address ":9001" /data`

Comment: Yes but how is --console-address declared in docker-compose.yml

Comment: There's a command to start the minio server either in the docker-compose, or in the Dockerfile that builds minio. Just need to add this flag to it and then add "9001:9001" to your port mappings

Comment: @sisko `command: ["server", "--console-address", ":9001", "/data"]`